# Django changing and saving objects of a QuerySet

Tags: django

I am trying to change a field in one element of the QuerySet and save it, but it doesn't seem to save. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong ?

```
objs = sampleModel.objects.all() 

# below code doesn't work
objs[0].text = 'NEW TEXT'
objs[0].save()

# below code does work
index = 0
for obj in objs: 
    if index == 0:
        obj.text = 'NEW TEXT'
        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read: [When QuerySets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

Related parts coped here:

> No database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate the queryset.
>
> ...
>
> Slicing. As explained in Limiting QuerySets, a QuerySet can be sliced, using Python’s array-slicing syntax. Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet, but Django will execute the database query if you use the “step” parameter of slice syntax, and will return a list. Slicing a QuerySet that has been evaluated also returns a list.
>
> Also note that even though slicing an unevaluated QuerySet returns another unevaluated QuerySet, modifying it further (e.g., adding more filters, or modifying ordering) is not allowed, since that does not translate well into SQL and it would not have a clear meaning either.

Particularly:

> Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet.

---

Now, simply try to understand the below code:

```
print(id(objs[0]))
print(id(objs[0]))
```

Output (in my machine):

```
4495005392
4495004112
```

#### We can see that they are not the same. They are different. objs[0] returns a `DIFFERENT` instance each time.

---

So, when you do:

```
objs[0].text = 'NEW TEXT'
objs[0].save()
```

We are operating on different instances.

- `objs[0].text` will modify `text` attribute of some instance (let's call it `instance1`).
- `objs[0].save()` will save `another instance` (not `instance1` another instance let's call it `instance2`). `instance2` will have the original value of `text` and saving it won't make any difference!

---

When we do:

```
objs = sampleModel.objects.all() 
obj = objs[0]
obj.text = 'NEW TEXT'
obj.save()
```

We are storing the instance returned by `objs[0]` in `obj` and **operating on the same instance in the following lines**, hence it will work.

---

When we do:

```
index = 0
for obj in objs: 
    if index == 0:
        obj.text = 'NEW TEXT'
        obj.save()
```

We are **operating on the same instance in the following lines**, hence it will work (similar to the above example).

Answer (score 0):

Save the object to a variable and then save() should work.

```
objs = sampleModel.objects.all() 

x = objs[0]
x.text = 'NEW TEXT'
x.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by casting the QuerySet to a list. Now it works.

```
objs = list(sampleModel.objects.all()) 
objs[0].text = 'NEW TEXT'
objs[0].save()
```

Comment: Yes, because by using `list()` you `evaluated` it. You can find more details in the link that I have mentioned in my answer. Thanks!